# Align Icons and text in QListView centered

Tags: alignment, qt4.8, qlistview

I want to align the items in the QListView centered like on this image:

[image]

Currently I manage to aligenn them only left:

[image]

In the property inpector of QtCreateor I have found nothing related to alignment. Also the style-sheet documentation for QListView tells nothing about the alignment.

Is this only to acheive using custom delegates?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to subclass the `QStyledItemDelegate` object which is responsible to customize the rendering of your items.

[Here is a link to the doc.](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html)

There are also some samples availaible on the Qt website:

[Star Delegate](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-stardelegate-example.html)

I comming back if I find a solution: I need the same effect as yours.